# How to select a value from Dropdownlist and pass value to Gridview?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I am having trouble with my SQL statement to pass the value from my dropdownlist select to my gridview.  I tested my SQL statement Serve Management Studio, with a specific date, and it works, but it isn't working with select value from my Dropdownlist.  How would I pass the value to the Gridview? Thank you for help, I am new student to the asp.net world.

Image of web application:
[image]
Image of My DATABASE:
[image]

```
public void RefreshDay()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"data source =.\sqlexpress; integrated security = true; database = DBdentist");
            SqlDataAdapter da = null;
            DataSet ds = null;
            DataTable dt = null;
            string sqlsel = "SELECT Distinct patient.patientID, day from patient, patientreservation where patient.patientID = patientreservation.patientID";


        try
        {

            da = new SqlDataAdapter();  
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlsel, conn);  
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "myDay");   
            dt = ds.Tables["myDay"];   


            DropDownListDay.DataSource = dt;
            DropDownListDay.DataTextField = "day";
            DropDownListDay.DataValueField = "patientID";
            DropDownListDay.DataBind();
            DropDownListDay.Items.Insert(0, "Select Day"); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LabelDay.Text = ex.Message; 
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close(); 
        }

    }



    protected void DropDownListDay_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownListDay.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"data source =.\sqlexpress; integrated security = true; database = DbDentist");
            SqlDataAdapter da = null;
            DataSet ds = null;
            DataTable dt = null;
            string sqlsel = "SELECT patientreservation.patientID, patient.firstname, patient.lastname, patientreservation.day, patientreservation.hour, treatment.treatment FROM((patientreservation INNER JOIN patient ON patientreservation.patientID = patient.patientID) INNER JOIN treatment ON patientreservation.treatmentID = treatment.treatmentID) WHERE patientreservation.day = " + DropDownListDay.SelectedValue + "";

            try
            {

                da = new SqlDataAdapter();  
                da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlsel, conn); 
                ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "myDay");  
                dt = ds.Tables["myDay"];
                GridViewDay.DataSource = dt; 
                GridViewDay.DataBind();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LabelDay.Text = ex.Message; 
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close(); 
            }

        }

        else
        {
            LabelDay.Text = "You choose None:";
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Is DropDownListDay.SelectedValue supposed to be a numeric value? Or is it like "Monday" or something like that

Comment: The datatype is a Date...  '2017-07-05'

Comment: SELECT patientreservation.patientID, patient.firstname, patient.lastname, patientreservation.day, patientreservation.hour, treatment.treatment 
  FROM ((patientreservation INNER JOIN patient ON patientreservation.patientID=patient.patientID) INNER JOIN treatment ON patientreservation.treatmentID = treatment.treatmentID)
  WHERE patientreservation.day = '2017-07-05'   This works fine when I test it, but when I add the selected value I start having problems

Comment: Those single quotes around the date aren't in your code.

Comment: I have tried the single quotes a few times without luck...

Comment: What about using parameters instead? Usually the best way to go

Comment: I can look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use this:

```
WHERE patientreservation.day = '" + DropDownListDay.Text.ToString() + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

The configuration of your dropdown is

```
DropDownListDay.DataTextField = "day";
DropDownListDay.DataValueField = "patientID";
```

but you need the **day** as a value if you want to filter with the current selected value

```
DropDownListDay.DataTextField = "day";
DropDownListDay.DataValueField = "day";

SELECT patientreservation.patientID, patient.firstname, patient.lastname, patientreservation.day, patientreservation.hour, treatment.treatment FROM((patientreservation INNER JOIN patient ON patientreservation.patientID = patient.patientID) INNER JOIN treatment ON patientreservation.treatmentID = treatment.treatmentID) WHERE **patientreservation.day** = " + DropDownListDay.**SelectedValue** + "";
```

Or you can try with `WHERE **patientreservation.day** = " + DropDownListDay.**SelectedText** + "";`

Comment: Still not able to view the grid-view, with these changes. It is very unhappy with the selected text.   DropDownListDay.DataTextField = "day";
DropDownListDay.DataValueField = "day";   Makes a lot of sense, but still unsure why it will not display

Comment: What you can do to solve the data type problem with datetime is something like $"WHERE DATEDIFF(dd, patientreservation.day, {DropDownListDay.SelectedValue}) =0";

If does not work try adding simple quotes

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I tried everything

`DropDownListDay.DataTextField = "day";
DropDownListDay.DataValueField = "day"`

helped.  I was also having some problem with my gridview.  I added up deleting it and making a new, somehow that help.

Answer (score -1):

The dropdownlist is not triggering the event. Try to put this AutoPostBack="true" in your asp dropdownlist tag.